# Cookies not being set but set on Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, setcookie

I am trying to set and retrieve a cookie. The code works perfectly fine on Postman, however, it does not work on my web browser. Initially, I thought the problem was caused by not setting the httpOnly method, but even after setting it to true, the issue still persists.

I have installed cookie-parser and used it, I console logged the cookie when its set and i get undefined. I checked my browser and also realized its not being set. Here is how i set the cookie

```
 const userEmail = req.body.email;
    const userDisplayName = req.body.displayName;
    res.cookie('usersEmail', userEmail, {maxAge: 1000000});
    res.cookie('usersDisplayName', userDisplayName,  {maxAge: 1000000});
```

Here is how i get the cookie

```
  const usersEmail = req.cookies.usersEmail
        const usersDisplayName = req.cookies.usersDisplayName
        console.log(req.cookies)
```

I tested my code on Postman and it seemed to work perfectly fine, so I don't think the issue is with how I set or retrieved it. However, despite setting the httpOnly method to true, it still didn't work on any of the browsers I tried (and I tried multiple ones). I also made sure that cookies weren't blocked for third-party sites, but the issue persisted.